# conditional execution of snakemake rules based on column in metatable

Tags: conditional-statements, snakemake

I'm trying to use a column in a text file to conditionally execute rules in a snakemake workflow.

The text file is as follows:

```
id  end sample_name fq1 fq2
a   paired  test_paired resources/SRR1945436_1.fastq.gz resources/SRR1945436_2.fastq.gz
b   single  test_single resources/SRR1945436.fastq.gz   NA
```

For each sample in the text file, if value in end column is paired I would like to use rule cp_fastq_pe and if end is single then I would like to use rule cp_fastq_pe to process the fq1 & fq2 or just fq1 files, respectively.

relevant part of Snakefile is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
samples = pd.read_table("config/samples.tsv").set_index("id", drop=False)
all_ids=list(samples["id"])

rule cp_fastq_pe:
    """
    copy file to resources
    """
    input:
        fq1=lambda wildcards: samples.loc[wildcards.id, "fq1"],
        fq2=lambda wildcards: samples.loc[wildcards.id, "fq2"]
    output:
        "resources/fq/{id}_1.fq.gz",
        "resources/fq/{id}_2.fq.gz"
    shell:
        """
        cp {input.fq1} {output[0]}
        cp {input.fq2} {output[1]}
        """

rule cp_fastq_se:
    """
    copy file to resources
    """
    input:
        fq1=lambda wildcards: samples.loc[wildcards.id, "fq1"]
    output:
        "resources/fq/{id}.fq.gz",
    shell:
        """
        cp {input.fq1} {output}
        """
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which I solved here: [How to make Snakemake input optional but not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227729/how-to-make-snakemake-input-optional-but-not-empty)

Here is the idea adjusted to your problem. First, you need to specify the `ruleorder` to resolve the ambiguity (otherwise the single could always be applied whenever the paired is possible):

```py
ruleorder: cp_fastq_pe > cp_fastq_se
```

Next, in your `cp_fastq_pe` rule you need to define a function that either returns a valid file (for the paired case) or returns a placeholder for non-existing file:

```py
rule cp_fastq_pe:
    input:
        fq1=lambda wildcards: samples.loc[wildcards.id, "fq1"],
        fq2=lambda wildcards: samples.loc[wildcards.id, "fq2"] if "fq2" in samples else "non-existing-filename"
```

This rule would be applied to all samples wherever `"fq2"` field exists and represents a valid file. The other rule would be selected to the rest of the samples.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I think this solution is on the right track but as it is the function in fq2 input gives a KeyError. To clarify, the goal is to have two versions of a few rules, with one version (e.g. rule_pe) that operates on two files formatted as follows: {id}_1.fq.gz and {id}_2.fq.gz and the other (rule_se) operating on a single file formatted as follows: {id}.fq.gz. Later in the workflow the output of the two versions of a rule will converge on {id}.txt for both, so I don't think it works to have fq2 be written to a random string for {id}.fq.gz case.

Comment: Whenever the fq2 is defined as a placeholder of non-existing file, this version of the rule cannot be used (and is not used): that is what you requested, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. The function doesn't work though. It produces KeyError: 0.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts on this. It now works when only paired sample is included in the samples file. When both paired and single are included receive a multiple of errors including `File path resources/fq//a.fq.gz contains double '/'.` and `WorkflowError (rule cp_fastq_pe, line 72, /path/to/Snakefile):
        Function did not return str or list of str.` Maybe it's more feasible to implement solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63323670/snakemake-rna-seq-how-can-i-execute-one-subpart-of-a-pipeline-or-another-subp)?

Comment: That is up to you which solution to prefer. To fix the problem I need to know both contents of the tsv file and full Snakenake script. Anyway, the advise I gave you is a key to solve the problem as you described in your initial question.

Comment: It appears that the problem was on my end. Your solution works. Thanks!